# how to add delete and update rows in DataGridView that mapped to the database by strongly typed dataSet but without auto generated form

Tags: c#, datagridview, strongly-typed-dataset

I have in my project this problem and I want to solve it by my hands, and I don't know how.
I have been made a lot of search on google but there is no a complete answer.
could any one have the unreachable solution for me " :P " .
how to add delete and update rows in DataGridView that mapped to the database by strongly typed dataSet but without auto generated form.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by  "without auto generated form." ?

Comment: I mean this code
             this.Validate();
            this.tableBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.typeddataSet);

Comment: Well you're going to have to have some code similar to that if you are using databinding - calling EndEdit on the BindingSource will push the data from the grid into the dataset, and then calling Update on the tableadapter will run your update command to get the data back into the database; so I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by saying you want to do it without that.